# Can't clone, push and pull from repositories in which I'm collaborator (Github desktop)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github

The issue I'm having is that GitHub Desktop doesn't let me clone, push or pull from repos in which I'm collaborator. The thing here is that in my other PC works fine but in my linux (ubuntu) pc it doesn't. I already checked the options and signed out/in again and reinstalled github desktop. When i try to clone it show the authentication failed and when I try to pull/push it shows `The repository does not seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed.`